# Replace terminal's vi with windowed vim for root

Tags: terminal, vi, macvim

I'm on Mac OS X, but I guess this is the same for other unixes.

Every time I type `vi` on the terminal, I want to open the GUI version of Vim (in Mac OS it's called `mvim`).

For my user, I got it working adding an alias on my ~/.profile:

```
alias vi='mvim'
```

But when I have to `sudo vi`, it opens the terminal's vi, because it doesn't have the alias set.

I tried setting the alias for the root user on `/etc/profile` but it did not work. I also tried making `/usr/bin/vi` a symbolic link to `mvim`, but it didn't work either.

How can I make it so evey time any user, including root, types `vi` on the Terminal, it opens the windowed Vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/profile` is not evaluated when you run `sudo ...` as far as I know and the problem with the symbolic link is the `mvim` script; if you look at it, it has these lines:

```
# GUI mode, implies forking
case "$name" in m*|g*|rm*|rg*) gui=true ;; esac
```

Since you started it with `sudo vi` the name does not fullfil the criteria to launch in GUI mode.

You could simply replace those two lines with `gui = true` to "force" GUI mode, but I am not sure what else this might break.